# Why did apt-get update fail?

Tags: 16.04

Why did `apt-get update` fail? What is cdrom in it?

[image]

Comment: Please do not make screenshots of text. Paste the text directly in your question. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

remove entry for `cdrom://Ubuntu16.04.....` and save the file.

then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```